# Does bufio.NewScanner in Golang reads the entire file in memory instead of a line each?

Tags: file, go, offset, seek

I was trying to read a file line by line with the following function using `bufio.NewScanner`.

```golang
func TailFromStart(fd *os.File, wg *sync.WaitGroup)  {

    fd.Seek(0,0)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fd)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        offset, _ := fd.Seek(0, 1)
        fmt.Println(offset)
        fmt.Println(line)
        offsetreset, _ := fd.Seek(offset, 0)
        fmt.Println(offsetreset)
    }
    offset, err := fd.Seek(0, 1)
    CheckError(err)
    fmt.Println(offset)
    wg.Done()

}
```

I was expecting it to print offset in increasing order, however, it is printing the same value in each iteration until the file reaches `EOF`.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2016:22:10:39 +0530] "GET /ttt HTTP/1.1" 404 437 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
613
613
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2016:22:10:42 +0530] "GET /qqq HTTP/1.1" 404 437 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
613
```

613 is the total number of characters in the file.

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | wc
  7      84     613
```

Am I understanding it wrong, or does `bufio.NewScanner` reads the entire file in memory, and iterates over that in-memory? If so, is there a better way to read line-by-line?

Comment: No, the default buffer size is 4096 bytes. Try it on a larger file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see `func (s *Scanner) Buffer(buf []byte, max int)` Docs:

> Buffer sets the initial buffer to use when scanning and the maximum 
>   size of buffer that may be allocated during scanning. The maximum 
>   token size is the larger of max and `cap(buf)`.
>   If `max <= cap(buf)`, 
>   Scan will use this buffer only and do no allocation.
>
> By default, Scan uses an internal buffer and sets the  maximum token
>   size to `MaxScanTokenSize`.
>
> Buffer panics if it is called after scanning has started.

And:

> MaxScanTokenSize is the maximum size used to buffer a token  unless
>   the user provides an explicit buffer with Scan.Buffer.  The actual
>   maximum token size may be smaller as the buffer  may need to include,
>   for instance, a newline.
>
> ```
> MaxScanTokenSize = 64 * 1024
>
> startBufSize = 4096 // Size of initial allocation for buffer.
> ```

No, as @JimB said it reads only buffer size, see this test sample:

For smaller than 4096 bytes it reads all file content to the buffer,
but for big files just reads 4096 bytes,
try this with big files:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Open("big.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    n, err := fd.Seek(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("n =", n) // 0

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fd)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        break
    }

    offset, err := fd.Seek(0, 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("offset =", offset) //4096

    offsetreset, err := fd.Seek(offset, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("offsetreset =", offsetreset) //4096

    offset, err = fd.Seek(0, 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("offset =", offset) //4096

}
```

output:

```
n = 0

offset = 4096
offsetreset = 4096
offset = 4096
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase your buffer size of your scanner

eg:-

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
buf := make([]byte, 0, 64*1024)
scanner.Buffer(buf, 1024*1024) //1024*1024 => 1mb max (you can change value here to read larger files
for scanner.Scan() {
    // do your stuff
}
```